# How to Call Class Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to Ruby, and I've been banging my head on what should be a stupidly easy problem for a while.

I'm starting off with a simple blog application (the one from the Ruby on Rails documentation), and I'm trying to augment it so that users can email posts. I have an email method in the post class working just fine, I'm just having a hard time calling it when a user clicks a link/button.

I realize that this isn't JavaScript and I can't just use an onclick. Perhaps one idea is to route to a link like blog/posts/2/email, but I don't even know where to start with that, and I wouldn't be surprised if there was a simpler approach.

Can someone please help a noob out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a controller action for the email delivery

```
def email_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.send_to(params[:email]) #send to is instance method on the model
  #assumes email address is being put in a form of some kind
end
```

Then create a route for the new controller method in routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'email_post'
  end
end
```

Finally make the form in your view and link it up to your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will send mail at post creation. If you want to tie it up with a separate button ("email me") you can move the code in create action to a new action (send_mail) and tie "email me" and "send_mail"

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def create
  post = Post.new(params[:post])
  Mailer.post_it(post).deliver
end
```

app/mailers/mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default :from => "noob@railstutorial.com"

   def post_it(post)
      @post = post

      mail(:to => "reader@hisdomain.com",
           :subject => "New Post: #{@post.title}",
           :cc => "admin@yourdomain.com")

   end
end
```

app/views/mailer/post_it.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
   </head>
   <body>
     <p><%= @post.content %></p>
   </body>
</html>
```